# Django + Pipeline to compress css: 404 for the output_filename css file

Tags: css, django, compression, settings, http-status-code-404

Configuration of Pipeline to compress css files is this:

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
                'colors': {
                          'source_filenames': (
                                               '/static/css/colors/colors.css',
                                               '/static/css/colors/layout.css'
                                               ),
                          'output_filename': '/static/css/Colors.css',
                    },
                }
```

but when the client tries to get

> /static/css/Colors.css
>   with

```
{% load compressed %}    
{% compressed_css 'colors' %}
```

it returns 404, Not found.
If i run `collectstatic` no files (like /static/css/Colors.css) are generated in STATIC_ROOT.

I have installed YUI Compressor from Synaptic Repository of my Ubuntu Lucid.

EDIT1:
Other of settings.py:

> PIPELINE_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineFinderStorage'
>
> STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
>
> PIPELINE=True

In middleware classes:

> 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
>
> 'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',
>
> STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
>       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
>       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
>      # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
>   )
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS = (
>       "/home/my/eclipse/myproject/static/",
>   )
>
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
>
> STATIC_ROOT = '/home/my/eclipse/myproject/static2/'

Comment: You need to specify relative paths to files, isn't you?

Comment: @neoasceetic i have static files out of the source folder. So i think that if i use relative paths the files aren't found.

Comment: Why so? Static files must be inside your source dir by defenition, unlike media files

Comment: Because source folder, that contains python code, is private, but the js and css files are public, so i have to distinguish this fact.

Comment: Why not copy/link this files?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative paths to source files since `pipeline` use `staticfiles` app to find this files.

Read more about [staticfiles management in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/?from=olddocs)

Comment: In this way the relative path starts from? From source folder? From project root folder?
If my project containes /myproject/static /myproject/src myproject/media, relative path start from /myproject folder? Or?

Comment: Paths starts from `static` folder. Because you can have many apps within your project and each can have static files inside it. So, if you have `/myproject/static/css/main.css`, relative path is `css/main.css`

Comment: Now i use relative path (for example 'css/colors/colors.css' ), but collectstatic doesn't generate the compressed files in STATIC_ROOT folder

Comment: Do you specify `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'` in your settings?

Comment: No, but just now i have added this setting, but the result is bad. No files are generated in STATIC_ROOT. Howeve now i will edit the question to specify better my settings.py

Comment: But should the compressed files be generated by collectstatic command? Or are there other ways to generate compressed files?

Comment: @GiovanniChetelodicoafare see here: http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#templatetags

Comment: Now it throws "ImproperlyConfigured: Finder "<class 'staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder'>" is not a subclass of "<class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.BaseFinder'>"
" exception

Comment: Sorry this last comment can be deleted: now it works fine, it remains problem about 404 of css/Colors.css

Comment: I have decided to pass to django-compressor. It seems working better and having better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the last line when you run collectstatic?

I noticed it writes to /tmp instead of STATIC_ROOT .

removing these 2 lines seems to fix it:

```
PIPELINE_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineFinderStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
```

( btw, the syntax has changed to {% load pipeline %} {% stylesheet 'colors' %} )